# What are some of these directories in the Linux kernel src?

Tags: linux-kernel

When I uncompress the Linux kernel source code from Kernel.org, there are many folders. I know what most of them contain and their purpose. However, I cannot figure out or find on the Internet the purpose for the tools and samples directories. What are these two directories and what is their purpose?

Comment: Uncompressing the kernel sources would leave you with a single non-compressed tar file. You probably meant you **extracted** the sources from the compressed tar.

Comment: Yes Anthon, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just uncompressed a kernel and this is what I make of it:

- For the `samples` directory, it's showing various examples of kernel modules people might want to develop. Here's a comment from `kprobe_example.c`:

> Here's a sample kernel module showing the use of kprobes to dump a
>   stack trace and selected registers when do_fork() is called.

and from `uhid_example.c`:

> The code may be used by anyone for any purpose, and can serve as a
>   starting point for developing applications using uhid.

etc, etc. Basically, anytime they felt a subject needed an illustration they wrote illustrative code and put it somewhere in this part of the directory tree.

- For the `tools` directory: This looks like a directory tree housing linux-specific executables. The bulk of a GNU/Linux platform's userland consists of cross-platform tools or tools created outside the Linux Foundation but occasionally the maintainers know there needs to be a userland tool in order to take advantage of features specific to the Linux kernel. The comments on most seem to include the word "simple" a lot which leads me to believe this directory tree is basically a userland equivalent of the `samples` directory. This is also because it doesn't look like util-linux comes from this (even though util-Linux does come from the Linux Foundation and kernel.org as well).